# How many people did "The Bride" kill

Tags: kill-bill

Tarantino's *Kill Bill* features Beatrix Kiddo a.k.a The Bride who goes on a killing spree killing all who wronged her at the chapel massacre.

How many people did she kill in all throughout the two movies.

Her kill count should include not only the Deadly Vipers but the others like the Crazy 88 gang and others.

Comment: Isn't this type of question considered trivia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this page at [allouttabubblegum](http://www.allouttabubblegum.com/main/?p=13537) the Bride's total body count is 70.

According to [moviebodycounts](http://www.moviebodycounts.com/Kill_Bill_1.htm) the Bride's total is 76. So that's my simple answer ruined.

Having said that, the [BFI](http://www.bfi.org.uk/news-opinion/sight-sound-magazine/comment/death-tarantino-style) says this about the House of Blue Leaves sequence:

> I’d still object to the sequence’s imprecision: it’s the first time it becomes impossible to get an accurate death count in Tarantino’s films (some of the actors playing the Crazy 88 gang are killed multiple times in the sequence).

I can't personally vouch for either of these figures though, as it's been a long time since I've watched the films.

Comment: I had the impression that she killed all but one of the crazy 88 and thus her kill score in that scene should be 87 or the 88, no matter how many deaths are seen onscreen.  So how could her total be only 70 or 76?

Comment: @M.A.Golding there are two things to consider about the Crazy 88 - firstly, there aren't 88 of them (in Volume 2, Bill says they picked the name because it "sounded cool") and The Bride doesn't kill all of them. She tells the survivors to leave the limbs they've lost behind, shortly before she ascends to the roof to fight O-Ren Ishii.
In the credits, there are 40 actors actually credited to members of the Crazy 88.

Comment: Her dialog at the end of the Crazy 88 fight is: "Those of you lucky enough to still have your lives take them with you.    
However...leave the limbs you've lost. They belong to me now."